# how to know where a file is even if it was moved? MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I was told that this was possible, its that true? I mean, if I have a txt file which contains a connectionstring in the View folder(its an example) and the url of that txt file is absolute and that file is move by another programmer to the Model folder, there will be an error. 
But as I said, someone told me there is a way to avoid that with razor. It that true? How?
Thanks.
Sorry if i didnt explained so well. Let me know

**Real ecenario**

I have a connectionstring in a txt file, if for some reason that file is move by someone else, the connection will fail. I cant allow that. I need a pice of code that find out that file wherever it is.

Comment: Instead of contrived examples - how about giving us the real scenario so that we can actually help.

Comment: Fire the programmer that put it in any location but / in the first place, then fire the person who moved it without checking the impact of their change

Comment: That's what the `/Web.config` file is for (see the `connectionStrings` element)

Comment: @Dan-o i know, but i must use it with a text file not with web.config

Comment: That's.. ridiculous.  But, whatever.  @ChrisBint has the correct answer in the comment above.

Comment: One reason the connection string should go in web.config is because IIS will block all requests for web.config. If you put your connection string in some text file IIS will be happy to send it to anyone. Potentially giving them information they can use to attack your DB.

Answer (score 2):

Connection strings should only go in the web.config, which should really only be stored in the root of the website.

Follow that and there will not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Connection String in a text file?
Ok, let me tell you that if someone gets the path of that file easily can download your precious credentials

how about learn good practices?

Comment: How about doing what you boss say first?

Comment: explain to him what kind of security risk are involved